# how to create datagrid at run time through code?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to create datagrid at runtime in and add it to one new tab.

C# 3.0 -- .net 3.5

Any starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy...

```
DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();

// set columns (auto or manual)

// set appearance (lots of style options)

// set data source (IEnumerable object)
dg.DataBind();

placeHolder1.COntrols.Add(dg); // add to placeholder
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn how to do this is to add data grid on design time and take a look on the auto generated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much the same as creating any control at runtime.

```
DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();
dg.ID = "grid";
....Other properties

this.tab.Controls.Add(dg);
```

[Just remember when dynamically creating controls they must be re-created on each postback](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)