# Can i create Datagrid through cs file without writing code in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to create multiple data grid tables in WPF using c#

1. But I am getting number to create tables runtime
2. So how to create multiple tables runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to create datagrid at run time through code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256100/how-to-create-datagrid-at-run-time-through-code)

Comment: Seeing as that's winforms, i don't think it does answer this wpf question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically create a datagrid in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120010/how-to-dynamically-create-a-datagrid-in-wpf)